# how to turn a list of strings in a list of objects?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings from an external text file. Each string is like this: `name job location`. What is the fastest way to turn each string into an object, creating a list of objects?

The objects are like this:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, job, location):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.location = location
```

Comment: What is the separator between each "name job location"?

Comment: I'm pretty new to python, so the only thing I tried is to modify manually the text file, I wonder if there's a way to automatize this task

Comment: there's no separator in the txt file, each string is exactly like that. I hope I don't have to add commas in every string

Comment: Almost certainly, but this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: yes, you automate these kinds of tasks by writing the code for it, something that reads the csv, and then passes each row to the class to create new instances. Having said that, we expect you to look up and learn the basic constructs provided by the language, so that we arent doing all your work for you.

Comment: @Skalfaro Instantiate an object of class `people` for each person in your text file?

Comment: I don't need to write code, it's not my job. I'm just asking which method is commonly used so I can do that myself

Comment: Your class should be called `Person`, not `people`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "people" is a bad name for this class. Typically, standard naming convention says classes should start with a capital letter. Also, a single instance of this class represents one person, not several people. I think a better name for this class is "Person".

Assuming you have a text file (`data.txt`) which looks like this:

```
Bob Teacher Alabama
Frasier Psychiatrist Seattle
```

And the code:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, job, location):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.location = location

    def get_info(self):
        return f"My name is {self.name}, and I'm a {self.job} in {self.location}."

def main():

    people = []

    filename = "data.txt"
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            person = Person(*line.split())
            people.append(person)

    for person in people:
        print(person.get_info())

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import exit
    exit(main())
```

The output:

```
My name is Bob, and I'm a Teacher in Alabama.
My name is Frasier, and I'm a Psychiatrist in Seattle.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the file line by line.
For each line you split it into the sub strings which are then name, job and location.
You can create a people object from these and push it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to open your file, read line by line, split the line on the spaces (since you don't want to add commas) and create the object:

```
p = []

with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(' ')
        p.append(people(values[0], values[1], values[2]))
```